# Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias using FilamentPHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

Using Filament PHP, i'm facing a problem with a relation, I can access the resource create view, and save the content (with all the relations fine), but the error appear when I open the edit view of the resource.

I think I need to know how modify my code to make the Filament use the correct joins.

The error:

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'machines_power_supplies'**

```
SELECT
  `machines_power_supplies`.*,
  `machines_power_supplies`.`machine_id` AS `pivot_machine_id`,
  `machines_power_supplies`.`model_id` AS `pivot_model_id`,
  `machines_power_supplies`.`name` AS `pivot_name`
FROM
  `machines_power_supplies`
  INNER JOIN `machines_power_supplies` ON `machines_power_supplies`.`id` = `machines_power_supplies`.`model_id`
WHERE
  `machines_power_supplies`.`machine_id` = 9
```

My Machine Model:

```
public function powerSupplies(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany(MachinePowerSupply::class, 'machines_power_supplies', 'machine_id', 'model_id');
}
```

My Pivot Model:

```
public function machine(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Machine::class, 'machine_id', 'id');
}

public function option(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Option::class, 'model_id', 'id');
}
```

The Option model is a generic model use in other resources, with a list of contents:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Options;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use App\Models\Options\OptionsList;

class Option extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'options';

    protected $fillable = [
        'options_list_id',
        'name',
        'value',
        'description',
    ];

    public function list(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OptionList::class, 'options_lists_id');
    }
}
```

Here's the part of the Form:

```
...
Select::make('power_supply_id')
    ->label(__('machines.power_supply'))
    ->relationship('powerSupplies', 'name')
    ->options(OptionService::getOptions('machine.power_supply'))
    ->multiple()
    ->searchable(),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After a hour... the obvious hit me hard! Changed the BelongsToMany, referencing the Option model, instead of pivot model.

```
public function powerSupplies(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany(Option::class, 'machines_power_supplies', 'machine_id', 'model_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public function powerSupplies(): BelongsToMany {
return $this->belongsToMany(MachinePowerSupply::class, 'machines_power_supplies', 'machine_id', 'model_id')
->withPivot('name'); // Assuming 'name' is the pivot column you're interested in
}